# tkinter .pack() not displaying frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame, customtkinter

I am trying to display another frame in the bottom left corner, however when I .pack() it, it does not display.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter

window = customtkinter.CTk()

window.geometry("1900x980")
#customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")

mainFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window, width=1900, height=980)
mainFrame.pack()
mainFrame.pack_propagate(0)

topFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(mainFrame, width=1870, height=110, corner_radius=10)
topFrame.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
topFrame.pack_propagate(0)

leftFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(mainFrame, width=400, height=825, corner_radius=10)
leftFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=15, pady=5)
leftFrame.pack_propagate(0)

rightFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(mainFrame, width=1460, height=825, corner_radius=10)
rightFrame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=15, pady=5)
rightFrame.pack_propagate(0)

bottomLeftFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(mainFrame, width=400, height=20, corner_radius=10, bg_color="red")
bottomLeftFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
bottomLeftFrame.pack_propagate(0)

window.mainloop()
```

To my understanding, if two objects are assigned `side=tk.LEFT`, then the second will be placed below the first one on the left hand side. However, this does not happen. Please see my output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLhTG.png).

Does any one know why this is? I have adjusted the height of both the left hand side frames so they should fit in the window.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  bottomLeftFrame is being packed to the left of rightFrame, and has the full height of rightFrame available to it; it doesn’t appear because there’s no width left for it.  Two-dimensional layouts like this are generally easier to accomplish with grid().

Comment: Is there a way I can do it with pack?

Comment: Hello? I am still struggling with .grid, I really liked the configuration I had with pack - is there a way you know how to do it?

Comment: Note that *"if two objects are assigned `side=tk.LEFT`, then the second will be placed below the first one on the left hand side."* is incorrect. The second one will be placed on the right of the first one. If you want `bottomLeftFrame` just below `leftFrame`, you need to pack the frames in this order: `topFrame` at top, `rightFrame` at right, `bottomLeftFrame` at *bottom*, `leftFrame` at *bottom*.